# Switching viewmodel inside controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, controller, viewmodel

Lets tell, i have multible categories, like motherboards, cases, and drives. Each of them have their own view with viewmodel, something like MotherboardsView, CasesView and DrivesView. And viewmodels - MotherboardsViewModel, CasesViewModel and DrivesModel.
I have controller where i wanna switch viewmodels based on category.
Abstract code would look something like this :

```
//GET Action
public ActionResult Create(string Category)
{
    switch (Category)
    {
        case "Motherboards":
            var viewModel = new MotherboardsViewModel { };
            break;
        case "Cases":
            var viewModel = new CasesViewModel { };
            break;
        default:
            var viewModel = new DrivesViewModel { };
            break;
    }

    //Here i use switched viewmodel to change some values, like:
    viewModel.Name = GetRandomName();
    ...

    //And i return view and viewmodel
    return View(Category + "View", viewmodel)
}
```

Is it possible, and how could i solve this problem?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: The part where i need to change viewmodel values gives "The name 'viewmodel' does not exist in current context ".

Comment: Right. You have a simple variable scoping problem. Declare `viewmodel` within scope of the return statement.

Comment: Could you give me some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic programming concept, not specifically related to MVC. Variables must be declared within "scope" of code that uses it. Your `viewmodel` is declared within the switch statement and cannot be seen outside of that code block. Try this which declares `viewmodel` such that it can be accessed by any code in the method. Notice `var` has been removed.

```
//GET Action
public ActionResult Create(string Category)
{
    object viewmodel = null;

    switch (Category)
    {
        case "Motherboards":

            MotherboardviewModel = new MotherboardsViewModel { };
            //Here i use switched viewmodel to change some values, like:
            MotherboardviewModel.Name = GetRandomName();
            ...
            viewModel = MotherboardviewModel;

            break;
        case "Cases":

            CaseviewModel = new CasesViewModel { };
            //Here i use switched viewmodel to change some values, like:
            CaseviewModel.Name = GetRandomName();
            ...
            viewModel = CasesviewModel;

            break;
        default:

            DriveviewModel = new DrivesViewModel { };
            //Here i use switched viewmodel to change some values, like:
            DriveviewModel.Name = GetRandomName();
            ...
            viewModel = DriveviewModel;

            break;
    }

    //And i return view and viewmodel
    return View(Category + "View", viewmodel)
}
```

Comment: Ok, thats true i just didnt know how to declare viewmodel. But declaring this way leads me to another issue: "object does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". I understand, that this is because we declared viewmodel as null object.

Comment: No, that would give null reference exception. You would have to cast it to the specific Type to access 'Name' because 'object' does not have a name property. It would be better if your vms implemented a common interface that has a name property so you don't have to use object.

Comment: I'm mobile now and can't fix my example. Simplest thing to do is repeat your code in each switch statement. Not good design but quick and dirty.

Comment: Yeah i just relized that too. Will write here correct solution too, after done testings. Thank you for your help :)